# jQuery returns not a number only when I use subtract

Tags: jquery, math, equation

I am having an issue with jQuery that I can't seem to figure out.

If I do `console.log($(window).width()/2)` I get a numerical value.

If I do `$('.modal_box').outerWidth()` I get a numerical value.

However if I try to do `console.log($(window).width()/2 - $('.modal_box').outerWidth())` I get NaN. If I do the same equation but replace the `-` with `+` it works.

The window width is always wider than the `.modal_box`.

Why could this be? It is very frustrating.

Comment: did you try this console.log(($(window).width()/2) - ($('.modal_box').outerWidth()))

Comment: Yeah this got it to work. Seems rather odd. Anyway thanks. I know it is another question, but why won't the modal_box sit center now. It is to the left of the page. Gah, can't catch a break.

Comment: It depends on the css for '.modal_box'. Without the markup, I assume '.modal_box' should have '**position**: absolute', be a direct sibling of the *body* element and have **left** set to ($(window).width()/2) - ($('.modal_box').outerWidth()/2) , if you want it to be positioned in the center of the screen.

Comment: Ah that is where I am going wrong then. I also assume you mean child as it can't be a sibling. Haha. But yeah, due to the way the content for the modal box is generated, it can't be direct descendant.

Comment: I just tried [it here](http://codepen.io/alexmccabe/pen/JEluH) and it works. Thank you. Will have to find another way of doing it on my site.

EDIT: Actually that works on my site as well now. Thanks. If you provide it as an answer I will vote it up.

Comment: @defau1t why would that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

try that

```
console.log(parseFloat($(window).width()/2) - parseFloat($('.modal_box').outerWidth()));
```

Comment: [`width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [`outerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) return ints.

Comment: The answer that was here before worked. Thanks. Now to figure out why the math doesn't sit the div directly center...

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes, but an int divide by 2 can be a float. And every int can be parse as float ;)

Comment: @algorhythm: I thought JavaScript didn't differentiate between ints and floats.

Comment: @RocketHazmat with parseInt you loose the decimal numbers (behind the ','). with parseFloat it works with decimals.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this just the way you did and it works good, even with negative values (when subtracting with a bigger number). Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dh6RG/), and here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    alert($('#someDiv').outerWidth());
    alert($(window).width());
    alert($('#someDiv').outerWidth() - $(window).width());
});
```

I believe that the error lies somewhere in the syntax or maybe (a long shot) if the css properties for width of the element are not provided.

Here is the additional information:

In order to position it in the center of the screen, '.modal_box' should have 'position: absolute', be a direct sibling of the body element and have left set to ($(window).width()/2) - ($('.modal_box').outerWidth()/2).

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with math and values returned by it, I usually prefer to parse the value to an integer explicitly so that I get only the value I'm after. I also like to make the code as readable as possible, like so:

```
var w = parseInt($(window).width()/2);
var mb = parseInt($('.modal_box').outerWidth());

console.log(w - mb);
```

That way it's easier to `console.log()` both values as well and understand why the operation is not returning a number.

Cheers!